# Access Google Analytics API via javascript with service account

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, oauth-2.0, google-analytics-api

Title pretty much says it all - I need to access Analytics data for a site, using the Javascript API and authenticating via a service account. Is this possible, if so, how? Have spent hours running in circles in the Google docs to no avail.

I'm looking to build a dashboard to publically display stats for the site, hence the need for the service account.

Javascript is a must - I need a completely client-side solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Analytics API access with a service account](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478764/google-analytics-api-access-with-a-service-account)

Comment: The anwser is still yes.  Maybe check your old questions before reposting the same question again would be a start.

Comment: Indeed it would. Didn't even remember asking the first time.