# I want to get an Access Token with Service Account at Google in JavaScript but get an error: invalid_grant

Tags: javascript, google-oauth, access-token, jwt, service-accounts

I've read the following references and tried to use the signed JWT to get an access token from Google, but in fail:

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

[How to obtain Google service account access token javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28751995/how-to-obtain-google-service-account-access-token-javascript)

http://kjur.github.io/jsjws/tool_jwt.html

I'm wondering that my code is almost the same with the second link([How to obtain Google service account access token javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28751995/how-to-obtain-google-service-account-access-token-javascript)) and still can't find out what's the problem with my code. That makes me so nervous.

The following is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1" />
<title>JWT(JSON Web Token) generator</title>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/jsrsasign-4.1.4-all-min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="ext/json-sans-eval-min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="jws-3.1.js"></script>

<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>    

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

function requestAccessToken() {
    var JWT = doSign();
    var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var urlEncodedData = "";
    var urlEncodedDataPairs = [];

//    urlEncodedDataPairs.push(encodeURIComponent("grant_type") + '=' + encodeURIComponent("urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer"));
//    urlEncodedDataPairs.push(encodeURIComponent("assertion") + '=' + encodeURIComponent(JWT));
    urlEncodedDataPairs.push("grant_type=" + encodeURIComponent("urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer"));
    urlEncodedDataPairs.push("assertion=" + encodeURIComponent(JWT));
    urlEncodedData = urlEncodedDataPairs.join('&').replace(/%20/g, '+');


    function writeResponse(jsonResp, rawResp) {
        document.myform.accessToken.value = rawResp;
    }

    var request = gapi.client.request({
            'path': '/oauth2/v3/token',
            'method': 'POST',
            'headers': {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
            'body': urlEncodedData
    });

    request.execute(writeResponse);

}

//JWS signature algorithm: SHA256withRSA with PKCS#8 plain private key(z4)
function doSign() {
    var sClaim = JSON.stringify(getClaim());

    var pHeader = {'alg': "RS256", 'typ': 'JWT'};
    var sHeader = JSON.stringify(pHeader);

    var key = myPrivateKeyPkcs8Pem;

    var JWT = '';
    JWT = KJUR.jws.JWS.sign(null, sHeader, sClaim, key);
    document.myform.jwt.value = JWT;

    return JWT;
}

function getClaim() {
    var r = {};
    r.iss = "<myserviceaccount>@developer.gserviceaccount.com"; 
    r.scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file";
    r.aud = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token";
    r.exp = KJUR.jws.IntDate.get("now + 1hour");
    r.iat = KJUR.jws.IntDate.get("now");
    //http://kjur.github.io/jsjws/api/symbols/KJUR.jws.IntDate.html#.get

    return r;
}

//skipped my private key
var myPrivateKeyPkcs8Pem = "" +
"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n" +
"MII...\n" + 
"-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <form name="myform">  
        <h4>Press "Sign it" to generate signed JWT!</h4>
        <input type="button" value="Sign it and get Access Token!" onClick="requestAccessToken();"/> <br/><br/>
        <div>JWT:</div>
        <textarea name="jwt" cols="65" rows="10"></textarea><br/><br/>
        <div>Access Token:</div>
        <textarea name="accessToken" cols="65" rows="10"></textarea><br/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the following is the headers:

```
<General>
Remote Address:XXX.XXX.XX.XX:443
Request URL:https://content.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token
Request Method:POST
Status Code:400 Bad Request

<Response Headers>
alternate-protocol:443:quic,p=1
cache-control:private, max-age=0
content-encoding:gzip
content-length:79
content-type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
date:Mon, 27 Apr 2015 20:55:59 GMT
expires:Mon, 27 Apr 2015 20:55:59 GMT
server:GSE
status:400 Bad Request
vary:X-Origin
vary:Origin
version:HTTP/1.1
x-content-type-options:nosniff
x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection:1; mode=block

<Request Headers>
Provisional headers are shown
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Origin:https://content.googleapis.com
Referer:https://content.googleapis.com/static/proxy.html?jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.zh_TW.SI1fBy9C-R8.O%2Fm%3D__features__%2Fam%3DIQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Ft%3Dzcms%2Frs%3DAGLTcCNsXEl0-sBYlv_cl9oHO7c1Y8AgBA
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36
X-ClientDetails:appVersion=5.0%20(Windows%20NT%206.1%3B%20WOW64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F42.0.2311.90%20Safari%2F537.36&platform=Win32&userAgent=Mozilla%2F5.0%20(Windows%20NT%206.1%3B%20WOW64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F42.0.2311.90%20Safari%2F537.36
X-Goog-Encode-Response-If-Executable:base64
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:google-api-javascript-client/1.1.0-beta
X-Origin:file://
X-Referer:file://

<Form Data>
view source
view URL encoded
grant_type:urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
assertion:<my JWT>
```

The folowing is what I get from google:

```
{"gapiRequest":{"data":{"body":"{"error": "invalid_grant",
                                   "error_description": "Bad Request"}",
                        "headers":{"date":"Mon, 27 Apr 2015 20:55:59 GMT",
                                   "content-encoding":"gzip",
                                   "expires":"Mon, 27 Apr 2015 20:55:59 GMT",
                                   "server":"GSE",
                                   "vary":"Origin, X-Origin",
                                   "content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8",
                                   "cache-control":"private, max-age=0",
                                   "content-length":"79"},
                        "status":400,
                        "statusText":"Bad Request"}}}
```

Comment: Maybe you should not encode the grant_type.

Comment: Thank you. But i've tried that and still get the same response ("Bad Request" ).

Comment: You have a Javascript page that contains a private key. You do realise why that is simply wrong?

Comment: Did you mean that "contains a private key in the JavaScript page" is not good?

Comment: @林佳蓉 Any luck ? please post how you solved it.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu  I didn't figure it out so i decided not to use the service account. I've read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-an-app-web-or-installed-without-user-intervention-canonic/19766913#19766913) for reference and solved my problem.  :)