# Oauth2 token response "invalid_grant" with JWT from GoogleAPI

Tags: javascript, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, jwt

I have enabled a Service Account from Google API Console to perform `two-legged OAuth` for making calls to Google Analytics API. I am using JavaScript and have followed the [pure JavaScript implementation of JWT and JWS](https://kjur.github.io/jsjws/) to generate a signed JWT and make the HTTP/REST call for a token as described in this [guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount). Once I make the `POST` with the encodedURL I get a 400 "error": "invalid_grant". "error_description": "Bad Request"

I read some posts to be sure to include the email and not `client_id` in request. I made sure that was the case and since then Google has updated their Documentation.

Any Ideas? I will post code also if necessary but I mostly followed [Rothrock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3591542/rothrock)'s post at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28751995/how-to-obtain-google-service-account-access-token-javascript/29288013#29288013).

I tried the signed JWT on http://jwt.io/ and it says it's invalid signature. The `payload` and `header` decode correctly. Is there a way to test the signature after encoding with private key provided by Google API console?

Here is my code:

```
  var pHeader = {"alg":"RS256", "typ":"JWT"};
  var sHeader = JSON.stringify(pHeader);
  var pClaim ={};
  pClaim.iss = "(ServiceAccount_Email_Address).apps.googleusercontent.com";
  pClaim.scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly";
  pClaim.aud = "htps://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token";
  pClaim.exp = KJUR.jws.IntDate.get("now + 1hour");
  pClaim.iat = KJUR.jws.IntDate.get("now");

  var sClaim = JSON.stringify(pClaim);

  var key = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- Private Key from JSON file ----END PRIVATE KEY-----"; 

  var sJWS = KJUR.jws.JWS.sign('RS256', sHeader, sClaim, key);
  var urlEncodedData = '';
  var urlEncodedDataPairs = [];
  var token;
  urlEncodedDataPairs.push("grant_type" + '=' + "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer");
  urlEncodedDataPairs.push("assertion" + '=' + sJWS);
  urlEncodedData = urlEncodedDataPairs.join('&').replace(/%20/g,'+');

 $(function(){
    $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token',
              data: urlEncodedData,
              dataType: 'JSON',
              contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
              success: function(result){
                console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
              }
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to this sometime back, but want to post it here for clarification. Everything in the code above is correct. The SSH key provided had some `\n` chars in it which are valid. My key had a line between `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` and the starting of the actual string of key.

Comment: So do I have to remove the 25 instances of "\n" in the private key?

Comment: No Brad You don't need to remove those.