# How to access Google Calendar API Bearer auth token?

Tags: javascript, heroku, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to set up [Google Calendar API push notifications](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push), but I don't know how to access the `auth_token_for_current_user` that I need in my POST request to the watch method. How do I access it?

I'm asking about the auth token part after the Bearer in the authorization header.

> POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/my_calendar@gmail.com/events/watch
>   Authorization: Bearer auth_token_for_current_user
>
> Content-Type: application/json

If it matters, my registered domain is a heroku instance. And I know how to retrieve calendar event info after going through the [javascript quickstart tutorial](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js).

Comment: For testing purposes, get an auth token from the [OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) and enable the Calendar API. Exchange authorization code for access token. Use that for now and tell us how it goes.

Comment: Refer to:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28751995/how-to-obtain-google-service-account-access-token-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I'm working through Python, but maybe someone will still need it.

If you were also trying to access via this method:  https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/python
Then my answer may help you.

Then after you successfully run the quickstart.py script, you will have a token.js file.
"token" - is your **auth_token_for_current_user**.
He is generated at every login with oAuth2. Correct me if I'm wrong somewhere. I am new to this topic

P.S. I'm not sure if you can get a token.json file on js either, but there's probably something similar there.

If you are trying to submit a request using [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) , it will end up looking something like this:

```
POST /calendar/v3/https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/my_calendar@gmail.com/events/watch/watch HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-length: 110
Content-type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer auth_token_for_current_user
{
  "id": "AnythingCanBeEntered", 
  "type": "web_hook",
  "address": "https://mydomain_com/notifications",
}
```

**my_calendar@gmail.com** can be taken from your google calendar settings -> **Calendar ID**