# Google Calendar API Issue with Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, require

I'm trying to use the google Calendar API to get all events from a G-Calendar. The following code works with Node.js

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');

const auth = new google.auth.JWT(
    CREDENTIALS.client_email,
    null,
    CREDENTIALS.private_key,
    SCOPES
);

const getEvents = async (dateTimeStart, dateTimeEnd) => {

    try {
        let response = await calendar.events.list({
            auth: auth,
            calendarId: calendarId,
            timeMin: dateTimeStart,
            timeMax: dateTimeEnd,
            timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata'
        });
    
        let items = response['data']['items'];
        return items;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`Error at getEvents --> ${error}`);
        return 0;
    }
};
```

But because I can't use the "require" in normal browser javascript it doesn't work.
I included
`<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>`
and
`const google = gapi;` instead of the `const {google} = require('googleapis');`

That in itself works but it does not recognize
`const auth = new google.auth.JWT()` as a function anymore and throws an `Uncaught TypeError: google.auth is undefined`

I would really appreachiate if someone could help. Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Does anybody have a hint?

Comment: Node is for server JS, have you tried implementing it following the [Javascript Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/js)?

Comment: @Kessy I know the quickstart guide. The issue is, that this is only user authenticated and I need to auth with a service account because I just wanna get all events from a calendar for a custom calendar javascript frontend app and some users might not have an account.

Comment: It's still an issue if someone has an idea it would be great!

Answer (score 0):

### If you need a client-side implementation for "normal browser javascript", you cannot use the [node.js implementation](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs)

Instead you would need to create a flow to obtain a Google service account access token. There is a good sample of how to implement it with XHR:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29288013/11599789

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I got a lot further, so far I can get an access token from the authentication service back but **I still struggle to access my calendar.**  <br/>
In node.js I would just use `const calendar = google.calendar({version : "v3"});` and then later `calendar.events.list({...})` but all this isn't working with pure browser javascript. It doesn't recognizes the first part and when I try `gapi.calendar.events` it throws `TypeError: gapi.calendar is undefined` back.   

**Did I forget to import something?**  
I used `https://apis.google.com/js/api.js`

Comment: Browser Javascript implementation for the Calendar API is very different. You need to start with the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/js) as a base to define gapi.

Comment: yeah but thats only for a sign-in process and not for a service account token. How do I combine these two?
And It's not even working when I just copied it and tried a run. It's really frustrating to work with an unclear documentation.

Comment: How do you have the script after this answer? Can you update the question with the script you have now?